# Access Java methods from JS

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, api

My web application working with third party REST APIs like Amazon API, Qwintry Logistic API, etc. I have made service layer with methods accessing these APIs, but I need work with the APIs from JavaScript as well.

I think best way is having access to my service methods (written in Java) from JS, instead of writing controllers which will call that methods after invoked from JS:

- JS code make ajax request
- Java controller invoke needed service method
- Service method make request to API
- API send back respond same long way full of mistakes and bugs

So question is can I and how call Java methods from JS code?

Comment: I assume the JS code runs on the client side so you need some form of web interface to access those services, e.g. a webservice.

Comment: Let me ask a clarifying question: Is your Java code acting as a "back-end", which you want your Javascript on the client-side to send AJAX calls to? If this is the case, you simply need to make the required call to your Java servlet or code using the specified routes

Comment: _I think best way is having access to my service methods (written in Java) from JS, instead of writing controllers which will call that methods after invoked from JS_ ...Why do you think that?

Answer (score 0):

This is called RMI (Remote Method Invocation).

You can use blank AJAX or some framework.
Just a few:

- http://async-io.org/
- https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/13/reactor-a-foundation-for-asynchronous-applications-on-the-jvm
- https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

But i bet they all use Ajax calls.